# Selenium not finding element by link text

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I try using 
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('2019')
but I get an error saying it was unable to find the element. I also tried using find_element_by_link_text('') and using the whole line but it wont work.
Ideas?

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('2019').click()
```

That is what I have been trying with nothing working.
Here is the webpage HTML:

```html
<div class="rowOf" id="tableRow1">
    <div class="tableD">
        <div class="productDiv" id="productDiv92195">
            <h2 class="productTitle" id="productTitle92195" onclick="goToProduct(0)">2019 Wall Calendar by Camoleaf</h2>
            <img class="productImage" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91j3pmPYDOL.jpg" onclick="goToProduct(0)">
            <hr>
            <h4 class="normalPrice" id="normalPrice0" onclick="goToProduct(0)">
                Normally: <span class="currency">$  </span>16.95
            </h4>
            <h4 class="promoPrice" style="margin:2.5px auto;" id="promoPrice92195" onclick="goToProduct(0)">
                Your Amazon Price: <span class="currency">$  </span>1.70
            </h4>
            <h3>Your Total: <span class="currency">$  </span>1.70</h3>
            <p class="clickToViewP" id="cToVP92195" onclick="goToProduct(0)">Click to view and purchase!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tableD">
        <div class="productDiv" id="productDiv69354">
            <h2 class="productTitle" id="productTitle69354" onclick="goToProduct(1)">Pure Lyft Energy Drink Mix (4 Pack) by PURELYFT</h2>
            <img class="productImage" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81kCgs96Z0L.jpg" onclick="goToProduct(1)">
            <hr>
            <h4 class="normalPrice" id="normalPrice1" onclick="goToProduct(1)">
                Normally: <span class="currency">$  </span>9.99
            </h4>
            <h4 class="promoPrice" style="margin:2.5px auto;" id="promoPrice69354" onclick="goToProduct(1)">
                Your Amazon Price: <span class="currency">$  </span>0.99
            </h4>
            <h3>Your Total: <span class="currency">$  </span>0.99</h3>
            <p class="clickToViewP" id="cToVP69354" onclick="goToProduct(1)">Click to view and purchase!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tableD">
        <div class="productDiv" id="productDiv79478">
            <h2 class="productTitle" id="productTitle79478" onclick="goToProduct(2)">Multi-Purpose Calf Compression Sleeves by DS Sports</h2>
            <img class="productImage" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91U7ExY-SfL.jpg" onclick="goToProduct(2)">
            <hr>
            <h4 class="normalPrice" id="normalPrice2" onclick="goToProduct(2)">
                Normally: <span class="currency">$  </span>12.95
            </h4>
            <h4 class="promoPrice" style="margin:2.5px auto;" id="promoPrice79478" onclick="goToProduct(2)">
                Your Amazon Price: <span class="currency">$  </span>5.05
            </h4>
            <h3>Your Total: <span class="currency">$  </span>5.05</h3>
            <p class="clickToViewP" id="cToVP79478" onclick="goToProduct(2)">Click to view and purchase!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an `id` you could perform the action on.  Why aren't you using that?  It is way faster and more reliable than `partial link text`.

Comment: The issue there is that the id changes everyday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your sample HTML, the only instance of "2019" is in an `<h2>` tag, not an anchor (`<a>`) link. Since `find_element_by_partial_link_text()` only searches anchor tags, it won't find it.

You can search via XPath to find an *arbitrary* element via partial text. Something like this:

```
all_matches = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(., '2019')]]")
all_matches[0].click()
```

That XPath says:

1. Search *all* elements (`*`)
2. Look at each item's `text()` in turn
3. If that `text()` `contains()` the string "2019", add it to the set of matches.

And of course we only click on the *first* element that matches.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("2019"));
You should use driver.findElement(By.linkText("2019"));
This again won't work as there are many calander in which the link text is 2019. So you need to provide a particular name.
Example, I did this :-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class AmazonShoping {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\priyj_kumar\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.in");
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("2019 Calander",Keys.ENTER);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("mapyourmonth Planner Organizer Diary Wall Calendar 2019")).click();
        //checking for a particular boat headphone say Boat BassHeads 900 Wired Headphone with Mic
//      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Boat BassHeads 900 Wired Headphone with Mic")).click();
//      String str = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mp-tfa']/p")).getText();
//      System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

This worked fine for me. Please let me know if I misunderstood the question somehow.

Comment: The question is in Python